# How to compute the more frequent value with spark

Tags: apache-spark

Given this `Dataframe` :

```
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  A|  1|
|  A|  2|
|  A|  1|
|  B|  3|
|  B|  4|
|  B|  4|
+---+---+
```

I want to compute for each value c1, the more frequent value of c2

```
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  A|  1|
|  B|  4|
+---+---+
```

Here is my current code (Spark 1.6.0)

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("A", 1), ("B", 3), ("B", 4), ("B", 4))).toDF("c1", "c2")
df.groupBy("c1", "c2")
  .count()
  .groupBy("c1")
  .agg(max(struct(col("count"), col("c2"))).as("max"))
  .select("c1", "max.c2")
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using Spark SQL the below implementation would work.
Please note that the window functions in Spark SQL is available from Spark 1.4 onwards.

```
df.registerTempTable("temp_table")

sqlContext.sql
("""
SELECT c1,c2 FROM 
(SELECT c1,c2, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY cnt DESC) as rank FROM (
SELECT c1,c2,count(*) as cnt FROM temp_table GROUP BY c1,c2) t0) t1 
WHERE t1.rank = 1
""").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("A", 1), ("B", 3), ("B", 4), ("B", 4))).toDF("c1", "c2")
```

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val overCategory = Window.partitionBy($"c1",$"c2").orderBy($"c2".desc)

val countd = df.withColumn("count", count($"c2").over(overCategory)).dropDuplicates

val freqCategory =countd.withColumn("max",max($"count").over(Window.partitionBy($"c1"))).filter($"count"===$"max").drop("count","max")